# Locate variables to a JSP in a dialog box

Tags: jsp

Good evening everyone,
it's been a few days that I'm stuck with a short code, I want the input data in the form, reappear in the dialog box for the user to be confirmed before the data it if someone an idea I would be grateful :)

```html
<form action="payer" method="GET">

    <br><br><br>
    <table  align="center" >
    <tr><td> Montant Dirham </td><td><input type="text" name="montant" id="t"> <input type="hidden" name="montant" value="${montant}"/></td></tr>

    <tr><td> Montant en lettre : </td><td> <p id="lettres">sortez du cadre.</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Bénéficiant </td><td><input type="text" name="beneficiant" > <input type="hidden" name="beneficiant" value="${beneficiant}"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Code compte  </td><td><input type="text" name="codeCompte"><input type="hidden" name="codeCompte" value="${codeCompte}"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Code banquaire     </td><td> <input type="text" name="CodeBanq"><input type="hidden" name="CodeBanq" value="${codeBanq}"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="signer" value="signer"></td><td><input type="submit" name="abandonner" value="Abandonner"></td> </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name" class="poplight">En savoir plus</a>

  //ma  boite de dialogue 
 <div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">

    <h3>${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name }</h3>

    <p>Montant:${montant} </p>
    <p> à Monsieur: ${beneficiant} </p>
    <p>code banquaire:${codeBanq} </p>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: To get more people to help, it might be better to translate into English (if possible). This is actually in the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ascalonian indeed, even Google Translate makes a mess out of it :S...